# Should you use a function for only one line of code?

Tags: python, function

I'm relatively new to python and I was wondering if it's always better to never write something twice. I'm currently making a program where at two points in the program the same sentence may need to be saved to a file (consisting only of that sentence).

Is it worth it to make a function for that? I was wondering since it now takes up 2 lines of code, but making a function would make it 4 (2 to define the function and 2 to call it).

Comment: It depends on the line of code in question.

Comment: I would likely made a handy, more generic function that can write any text to any file, so both are passed in, then the function is more reusable later

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wrap even a one-liner in a function if

- Calling the function looks simpler than the code it wraps;
- It is likely to be repeated several times in your code;
- It is likely to change (then you change only the body of the function and not every place where it is used).

AFAIK, unlike in languages like C where simple functions can get inlined by the compiler, in Python there will be a (sometimes important) performance overhead in calling a wrapper function.

Answer (score 0):

When to create a function depends a lot on the specifics of the situation. It isn't just about saving lines of code - often, more lines of code is better because it makes it easier to maintain or easier to understand.

One reason to make a function is that it means if you need to change your code, there is just one place you have to change it.

It's unclear to me from your situation if you should create a function or not. It depends on the line of code. If the line of code is just calling another function, then wrapping that in another function doesn't make sense. If it's some complicated line that has lots of parts subject to change, then it might make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean assign a variable (by that I mean x = 7, or rate = getSamplingRate(sound)/2) or write a function?  I try to assign variables when I use them several times or if it makes the code easier to read.

if you mean define a new function like this:

```
    def newSentence():
```

then I would write a new function if I am doing the same thing several times.  It wouldn't hurt to define a function if you are performing the same action more than once.

I think a good rule of thumb when you're starting out is to first get your code to work, then make sure it is easy to read (for yourself, or for another person reading your program), then focus on efficiency.

I'm sort of new to Python as well. I hope that helps.